# how to make map painting software in Java

Tags: java, paint

Currently I am making painting program in Java with mouse click. Just like Photoshop or painting application in Microsoft.
I know it is easy to paint square shape, by setting  boundaries with X and Y axis. But how can I make method of painting complicated shape like the countries in map of Africa with mouse click? Is there way to set boundaries for this? 
Can anyone give me hint? Thank you!
[map of Africa example](http://www.yourchildlearns.com/images/africa-map.gif)

Comment: this is not code providing site. Share whaat you have tried then if you have some exact issue we will help. Kindly visit tour.

Comment: Figure out how you would about drawing a single line

Answer (score -2):

Painting is possible with java `Graphics`. Try following simple code.

```
public class PaintCanves extends JPanel {

    private int oldX;
    private int oldY;

    public PaintCanves() {
        draw();
    }

    private void draw() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                oldX = e.getX();
                oldY = e.getY();
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                getGraphics().drawLine(oldX, oldY, e.getX(), e.getY());
                oldX = e.getX();
                oldY = e.getY();

            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(new PaintCanves());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**This is my testing result.**

[image]

**Note:**

It clears the already drawn data when calling `repaint()` the panel. It's need to keep painting points safe using a technique such adding painting points into a `Collection` or something.

Comment: .... and please do tell me what happens when you minimize and then restore your GUI? Does your drawing persist? Please don't give misleading advice such as to use `getGraphics()` as you're doing above. Drawing in Swing is passive and should be done in the paintComponent method as is well explained painting tutorials: [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Comment: the panel repaints. so it will loss all data already drawn. i just tried to show you how to draw using mouse with java.

Comment: Yes, and you showed the original poster the **wrong** way to do this!

Comment: Think a little bit man. why don't you keep painting points in a `Collection`. Then redraw overriding `repaint()` method

Comment: `"Think a little bit man"`??  -- I know how to draw with Swing -- you may be confusing me with the original poster, but as for myself, I have answered over 11,000 questions on Swing on this site, much of them related to Swing graphics and drawing. If you improve your answer though I'll happily remove my down-vote. If you write a decent answer, I'll change it to an up-vote. If I were doing this though, I'd likely draw onto a BufferedImage and then display that image within the paintComponent method since the image display is faster, but using a `List<Point>` could work as well.

Comment: or `List<Shape>` if you wanted areas that are clickable.

Comment: You should understand the logic, don't except full source code without doing anything. You have to follow my logic definitely to do this, wherever you paint the component.